# Python PIL cut words out so it becomes transparent PNG

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, transparent

I would like to know if its possible with python pil to cut text out and make the picture transparent. Here is an example to explain it better. Picture 1.png is a circle. [image: Picture 1.png]

Picture 2.png is text.png that just says thanks. What I would like to do is put picture2 into picture1 and cut that out so it becomes transparent. so it should look like this picture3.png

[image: Picture2]
[image: Picture3]

This is what I have so far but it only pasting the image. I am new to PIl. I am not sure how to tell python I want this cut out like that.

```
img = Image.open('picture1.png').convert("RGBA")
bg_w, bg_h = img.size
layer = Image.open('picture2.png').convert("RGBA") # this file is the transparent one
img_w, img_h = layer.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w)/2, (bg_h - img_h) / 3)
img.paste(layer, offset, mask=layer)
img.save('Picture3.png')
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, in principle. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What specific part can't you manage? Are all of your images (and text images) b&w?

Comment: Take the letters, set everything white to completely transparent, paste it to the other image, adjust the alpha channel of the letter pixels

Comment: Yes all are black and white

Comment: [adjust the alpha channel of the letter pixels] how do u do that?

Comment: @benolsen my point was that your question is very low on details, shows no effort of yours to (even partially) solve the problem, and is likely to get very bad answers, or answers you don't understand (like max's), or more likely, no answers at all

Comment: I would like to show effort but I am very new to this module. I work better with examples so that I can play around and tweak it (thats how I learn). I also want to speed up my learning curve as fast as possible. Instead of spending the next 2 weeks learning it from the ground up. I hope this clarifies any misunderstandings. Thank you for help

Comment: But you do realize that it's impossible to answer your question without actually writing the entire code for you? No one will do it, probably, and even if they did then you'd probably won't understand much of it anyway... so how does that help?

Comment: your opinion is greatly appreciated and you are right. But here its 3:30AM and I have no energy to spend the next hour looking through all of these forums. All I want to know is how to adjust the alpha channel. So that I can play around with it for the next 30min. Help a brother out if you want :). I know how to paste 1 image to another image I just dont know how to cut it out. links are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Here is the answer:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.open('circle.png').convert("RGBA")
layer = Image.open('Thanks.png').convert("RGBA") # this file is the transparent one
img.paste(layer, mask=layer)
img.save('Picture3White.png')


img = Image.open('Picture3White.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("Transparent.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: In the images you provide, the text "Thanks" is bigger than the circle. You don't seem to correct for that in this code. How do you then end up with the word "Thanks" inside the circle?

Comment: I also see that you use the exact value for white (255,255,255,0), but in the png files you provide, the pixels are not exactly so black and white, e.g. (0, 1, 1, 51).